# Populate missing data points in azure dataflow

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

We are working on building ETL pipeline using Azure data flows.

Our requirement here is have to fill in the missing data points (add rows as required) and data for it to be copied from the previous available data point ( when sorted on key columns )

Example -

If the input data is :

[image]

The output should be like this:

[image]

The rows highlighted in green have values copied from previous available key columns ( Name, year and period )

Any idea how i can achieve the same in azure data flow.

Comment: Would fill-down solve this for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-script#fill-down

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of mapLoop function to generate years + quarters in 1 column. Then flatten tx it to get a table of years+quarters. Then left outer join that table to the original table.

You will have the resulting tables with nulls for the missing quarters. Then use the filldown technique to fill in values(this only works for small data)